# hibernate search, existing data not searchable

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

i seem to be missing something during initialisation of hibernate search.
my mysql database table **contains a few existing rows which dont seem to be returned as part of the results**
any new rows that i add through the application after starting it seem to be returned in the hibernate search

i need to return all rows including the ones already existing in the table, what do i need to add to get it?

this is the code section i use to query

```
    // get the full text entity manager
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager=Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

    //create query using hibernate query DSL
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder=fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Entity.class).get();

    // actual query
    Query query=queryBuilder.keyword()
            .onFields("col1","col2","col3")
            .matching(searchKeyword)
            .createQuery();

    //wrap Lucene query in hibernate query object
    FullTextQuery jpaQuery=fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, Entity.class);

    return jpaQuery.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run the [mass indexer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.5/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex-massindexer) to add all those entities to the index which have been added/updated while Hibernate Search was not (yet) enabled.

This will fetch all the entities from the database und update the corresponding index(es). In its simplest form it's done like so:

```
fullTextEntityManager
    .createIndexer( Entity.class )
    .startAndWait();
```

The reference guide describes all the options for fine-tuning in detail.

Comment: thank you, that worked. i guess i was supposed to RTFM :)